# "И" versus "Й" in Russian

Tags: произношение, буквы, фонетика

What is the difference in pronunciation between "и" and "й"?

They sound very similar and I can't really hear a difference.

Comment: Can you provide a couple of words where you cannot hear the difference between "и" and "й"?

Comment: й is a consonant, и is a vowel. How one can confuse them?

Comment: Interesting fact: do you know that Ь was "Е краткое" and Ъ was "О краткое" (or Ы, or something between О and Ы) once in old Russian?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I repeat, й is not a vowel, it is a consonant like "y" in "yes".

Comment: @Anixx because и and й are pronounced, respectively, [i] and [j], and both the IPA vowel [i] (pronounced in "ee" in the words "see", "bee" and "fee" in English) and the IPA semivowel [j] (pronounced in "y" in ""young") sound similar. The ear doesn't know if these Russian letters are classified as vowels, semivowels or consonants, just that they sound alike.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista, no, й is never read as ee in see. Й is a consonant (fricative, voiced, soft)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Russian "и" is a vowel and sounds more like the 'ee' in "tweet", while "й" is a consonant and sounds more like the first sound of "young". Btw, you could try listening to words on http://www.lingvo-online.ru/ to hear the difference.

Answer (score 12):

**Oй** rhymes with "joy" and **ои** rhymes with "Joey".

Comment: Cute way of explaining the difference! Not very accurate though.

Comment: I agree with @InitK. "joy" is pronounced /dʒɔɪ/ and the Russian letter й is pronounced /j/ , so this is a bad example.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Actually, joy is pronounced [dʒɔj]. The notation [ɔɪ] and [oʊ], to give just two examples, is outdated and unfounded. Modern phoneticians (of which I'm one) know better. Here's an interesting video on the subject: https://youtu.be/gtnlGH055TA?si=pJ-pU2q2AO4iYMSw

Answer (score 1):

Russians transliterate *boy* as *бой*. The word *бои* is a plural form of *бой* and is pronounced distinctly differently — something like *buyee*.

So *и* is a vowel and sounds longer than the consonant *й*. Your confusion stems from the feature of Russian pronunciation where Russian sticks an invisible *й* in front of many vowels, which makes them sound a little longer. For instance, when Russians say *ем* (I'm eating), they actually say something like *yem*. So in the first example *бои* has that invisible *й* in front of *и*.

Answer (score 1):

The Russian "и" sounds like the vowel [i] in the International Alphabetical Alphabet (IPA) and like the letters 'ee' in the English words "bee", "see" and "tweet".

The Russian й" sounds like the semivowel/consonant [j] in the IPA and like the letter 'y' in the English words "young", "year" and "you", and the letter 'u' in the English words "use" and "unit".

The difference between both is that the middle part of the tongue is raised to the hard palate only in [j]. I suggest watching this video: https://youtu.be/XhqGU1WxOfc .

Answer (score -3):

и = "i"
й = more like "y"

You can hear the difference by listening to the "i" and "y" sounds in two different words: "boy" and "blink", in first case it will be "boy" = "бой" while in the second "blink" = "блинк"

Comment: **и** is _[ˈaɪ]_ and **й** is _[ˈwaɪ]_? I don't think so.

Comment: Did you read my comment to it's very end?

Comment: Yes, I did read your ANSWER to its very end. But it doesn't make your first statement correct. Transliteration rules you used are not applicable in this case.

Comment: Okay, but if we'll be honest then we can only compare mentioned by you [ˈwaɪ] to "и краткая" right?

Comment: й is pronounced as /j/ in Russian, but the letter "y" is not always pronounced as /j/  in English. Using your example, "boy" is pronounced /bɔɪ/ (i.e., the "i" is pronounced as a /ɪ/ instead of a /j/) (ref: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/boy). The words "yes" or "you" would be better examples.